# How to display desired attributes in Woocommerce email order

Tags: php, email, woocommerce, attributes, orders

At present, my email order displaying all the attributes which are there on the product page. However, I only want to display some attributes like color and delivery.

```
/templates/emails/email-order-items.php
```

Here is the code... What changes do I have to do?

```
// Variation
        if ( $item_meta->meta ) {
            echo '<br/><small>' . nl2br( $item_meta->display( true, true ) ) . '</small>';
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Variation
    if ( $item_meta->meta ) {
        echo '<br/><small>' . nl2br( $_product->get_attribute( 'delivery' ) ) . '</small>';
    }
```

This code worked like a charm!! Wow thanks to myself B-)...

Comment: Would you be so kind telling us where to put this code in email-order-items.php? I have tried putting it below // SKU but without luck..

Comment: You should check it properly. $_product might be $product in your case or some other reason.